# In Xamarin, Cannot get the specific value from my php database, do I need a DeserializeObject?

Tags: c#, php, xamarin

This is where I get my data.

```
        $contacts = array(); 

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) 
        {

            $contact = array("ID" => $row['ProduktID'],
                             "Name" => $row['ProduktNamn'],
                             "Number" => $row['ProduktPris']);

            array_push($contacts, $contact);
        }

        echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And now when I use it in my code in Xamarin I can write the entire thing out in the log but not when I try to write out a certain "Name" of a table for example. This is the code:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getOurMainInfo()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost/getmystuff.php");

        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

    //  var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(resultString); //Should I implement this somehow to my JObject? Contact is my public class.

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult["Name"]); //i get nothing in the log. if i remove ["Name"] i get the entire data in the log.

        return jsonResult;

    }
```

My public class (If i need this to connect and work with th edatbase somehow):

```
public class Contact
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your PHP is returning an array containing another array.  Why?  How many rows does your query return?  Have you learned how to use the debugger yet?  If so then you could examine the results of JObject.Parse() and see exactly what it contains and why your logic isn't working.

Comment: I have 2 rows in my database. In my last thread someone gave me the arraysolution and it works with an JObject now atleast. If i remove the last array,the app crashes giving me the error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value :<.Path", line 0, position 0.

Comment: it loads twice in my log when i launch the app though. black text and then blue text. weird, never seen that b4.

Comment: if you are returning two rows of data, then what do you expect jsonResult["Name"] to do?  Print out the name for the first row, or the 2nd?  You need to decide what you want the program to do, then write the code to do that.  You appear to be writing code before you've decide what the logic should be, which is a common source of bugs.

Comment: I want to print out every ["Name"]. To have two arrays in my phpcode might be wrong though

Comment: So i cannot reach all of the names in my database now because I have two arrays? If I remove 1 of the arrays and still make it come as a single object, will i reach all the names then by typing ["Name"]?